# Calculate size of hexagonal map libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a staggered hexagonal map created with "tiled" map editor and I want to calculate the height of this map in pixels, the example map below should be `MAP_WIDTH_IN_PX = 1056` and `MAP_HEIGHT_IN_PX = 303;`

[image]

```
MAP_WIDTH = map.getProperties().get("width",Integer.class); //16 tiles
MAP_HEIGHT = map.getProperties().get("height",Integer.class); //5 tiles
TILE_WIDTH = map.getProperties().get("tilewidth",Integer.class); //64px
TILE_HEIGHT = map.getProperties().get("tileheight",Integer.class); //84px
TILE_SIDE_LENGTH = 27; //this value is set in the map editor


MAP_HEIGHT_IN_PX = ?;
MAP_WIDTH_IN_PX = MAP_WIDTH * TILE_WIDTH + TILE_WIDTH * 0.5f;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just check even and odd number of tiles in column, than half of them take tile height space and half tile width space. In case of odd number take care of last one.

```
if (MAP_HEIGHT%2==0) 
  MAP_HEIGHT_IN_PX = MAP_HEIGHT/2*TILE_SIDE_LENGTH+MAP_HEIGHT/2*TILE_HEIGHT;
else 
  MAP_HEIGHT_IN_PX = (MAP_HEIGHT-1)/2*TILE_SIDE_LENGTH+(MAP_HEIGHT+1)/2*TILE_HEIGHT;
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, this give me `380` and the map height is `303` however I  replcaced `TILED_WIDTH` with `TILE_SIDE_LENGTH` and it gave me `306` close but the bigger the map the bigger is the error

Comment: It seems that 3 is one px for long tile. Just add (MAP_HEIGHT/2) or in case of odd number of tiles  ((MAP_HEIGHT+1)/2) . Can be something in overlapping itd. Experiment it.